# Notice of request to your driver

Tags: android

Am trying to send a request from a rider to a driver like uber. Am using Firebase Cloud Messaging
I don't have any errors on my code but I can't seem to send the request.

I got this tutorial on youtube anyone please check out my code and let me know what i am doing different.

DriverActivity.class

```
public class DriverActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

public static GoogleMap mMap;

//play services res
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7000;
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RES_REQUEST = 7001;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
private static int FASTEST_INTERVAL =3000;
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;
DatabaseReference drivers;
GeoFire geoFire;


Marker mCurrent;
MaterialAnimatedSwitch location_switch;

SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
ImageView ivPin;

private List<LatLng> polyLineList;
private Marker carMarker;
private float v;
private double lat,lng;
private Handler handler;
private LatLng startPosition, endPosition, currentPosition;
private int index,next;
private PlaceAutocompleteFragment Places;
private String destination;
private PolylineOptions polylineOptions, blackPolylineOptions;
private Polyline blackPolyline, greyPolyline;

private IGoogleAPI mService;

Runnable drawPathRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (index<polyLineList.size()-1){

            index++;
            next = index+1;
        }
        if (index <polyLineList.size()-1){

            startPosition = polyLineList.get(index);
            endPosition = polyLineList.get(next);
        }

        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                v = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                lng = v*endPosition.longitude+(1-v)*startPosition.longitude;
                lat = v*endPosition.latitude+(1-v)*startPosition.latitude;
                LatLng newPos = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                carMarker.setPosition(newPos);
                carMarker.setAnchor(0.5f,0.5f);
                carMarker.setRotation(getBearing(startPosition,newPos));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                        new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(newPos)
                                .zoom(15.5f)
                                .build()));
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();
        handler.postDelayed(this,3000);
    }
};

private float getBearing(LatLng startPosition, LatLng endPosition) {

    double lat = Math.abs(startPosition.latitude - endPosition.latitude);
    double lng = Math.abs(startPosition.longitude - endPosition.longitude);

    if (startPosition.latitude < endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude <endPosition.longitude)
        return  (float)(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)));
    else if (startPosition.latitude >= endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude < endPosition.longitude )
        return (float)((90-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)))+90);
    else if (startPosition.latitude >= endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude >= endPosition.longitude)
        return (float)(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat))+180);
    else if (startPosition.latitude < endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude >= endPosition.longitude )
        return (float)((90-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)))+270);

    return -1;
}


//Car animation




TableRow myAccount, history, payments, notifications, invite, help, about, driveWithTowMe;
TextView name, email;
ImageView profilePicture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    location_switch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
    location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(boolean IsOnline) {
            if (IsOnline){
                startLocationUpdates();
                displayLocation();
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are online", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }else {
                stopLocationUpdates();
                mCurrent.remove();
                mMap.clear();
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawPathRunnable);
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });

    polyLineList = new ArrayList<>();
    ivPin = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPin);
    Places = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    Places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            if (location_switch.isChecked()){
                destination = place.getAddress().toString();
                destination = destination.replace(" ", "+");

                getDirection();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(DriverActivity.this, "Please change your status to ONLINE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(DriverActivity.this, ""+ status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    //geo fire

    drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.tow_driver_location_tbl);
    geoFire = new GeoFire(drivers);

    setUpLocation();

    mService = Common.getGoogleAPI();

    updateFirebaseToken();





    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);

    myAccount = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.myAccount);
    history = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.history);
    payments = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.myPayments);
    notifications = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.notifications);
    help = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.help);
    about = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.about);
    driveWithTowMe = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.DriveWithTowMe);

    myAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openMyAccount =  new Intent(DriverActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(openMyAccount);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
//                finish();
        }
    });

    history.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openNotifications = new Intent(DriverActivity.this, TripBill.class);
            startActivity(openNotifications);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });

    payments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openNotifications = new Intent(DriverActivity.this, EarningsFragment.class);
            startActivity(openNotifications);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });

    notifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openNotifications = new Intent(DriverActivity.this, NotificationsFragment.class);
            startActivity(openNotifications);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });


    help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openHelp = new Intent(DriverActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(openHelp);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
    driveWithTowMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });


    about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openAbout = new Intent(DriverActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(openAbout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });




}

private void updateFirebaseToken() {
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference tokens = db.getReference(Common.token_tbl);

    Token token = new Token(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
    tokens.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .setValue(token);

}

private void getDirection() {

    currentPosition = new LatLng(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(),Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude());

    String requestApi = null;

    try {

        requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+
                "mode=driving&"+
                "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"+
                "origin=" +currentPosition.latitude+ "," + currentPosition.longitude + "&" +
                "destination="+ destination +"&"+
                "keys="+ getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);

        Log.d("EDMTDEV", requestApi); //Print URL for debug

        mService.getPath(requestApi)
                .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                            for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)

                            {
                                JSONObject route = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                                String polyline = poly.getString("points");
                                polyLineList = decodePoly(polyline);


                            }
                            //Adjusting bounds

                            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                            for (LatLng latLng:polyLineList)
                                builder.include(latLng);
                            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                            CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 2);
                            mMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);

                            polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            polylineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                            polylineOptions.width(5);
                            polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                            polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                            polylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            polylineOptions.addAll(polyLineList);
                            greyPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);


                            blackPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            blackPolylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                            blackPolylineOptions.width(5);
                            blackPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                            blackPolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                            blackPolylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            blackPolylineOptions.addAll(polyLineList);
                            blackPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(blackPolylineOptions);

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(polyLineList.get(polyLineList.size()-1))
                                    .title("Pickup Location"));


                            //Animation

                            ValueAnimator polyLineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,100);
                            polyLineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                            polyLineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                            polyLineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

                                    List<LatLng> points = greyPolyline.getPoints();
                                    int percentValue = (int)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                                    int size = points.size();
                                    int newPoints = (int) (size * (percentValue/100.0f));
                                    List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0,newPoints);
                                    blackPolyline.setPoints(p);

                                }
                            });
                            polyLineAnimator.start();

                            carMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition)
                                    .flat(true)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.towin)));


                            handler = new Handler();
                            index=-1;
                            next=1;
                            handler.postDelayed(drawPathRunnable,3000);



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(DriverActivity.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });




    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private List decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List poly = new ArrayList();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
//Press Ctrl+O
//Because we request runtime permission, we need override OnRequestPermissionResult method


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){

        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:

            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&  grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                if (checkPlayServices()){

                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();

                    if (location_switch.isChecked()){

                        displayLocation();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

private void setUpLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  )
    {
        //Request runtime permissions

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    } else {

        if (checkPlayServices()){

            buildGoogleApiClient();
            createLocationRequest();

            if (location_switch.isChecked()){

                displayLocation();
            }
        }

    }





}

private void createLocationRequest() {


    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);




}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,this,PLAY_SERVICES_RES_REQUEST).show();

        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  ){
        return;
    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}


private void displayLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  ){
        return;
    }

    Common.mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (Common.mLastLocation != null){

        if (location_switch.isChecked()){
            final double latitude = Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            final double longitude = Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            //update to firebase

            geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                    //Add Marker

                    if (mCurrent != null)
                        mCurrent.remove();



                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .title("Your Location"));


                    //move camera to this position

                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15.0f));

                    //Draw animation rotate marker

                }
            });
        }
    }
    else {

        Log.d("ERROR", "Cannot get your location");

    }


}

private void rotateMarker(final Marker mCurrent, final float i, GoogleMap mMap) {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final float startRotation = mCurrent.getRotation();
    final long duration = 1500;

    final LinearInterpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/duration);
            float rot = t * i + (1 - t ) * startRotation;
            mCurrent.setRotation(-rot > 180?rot/2:rot);

            if (t<1.0){

                handler.postDelayed(this,16);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  ){

        return;
    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Common.mLastLocation = location;
    displayLocation();

}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    displayLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

I don't know why I can't send the send notification

Comment: Just mention the relevant code for this context

Comment: Trademark capitalization; spelling; grammar